# Blazor - Hide the side and top bar on a specific page (not for the whole site)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm making an app in Blazor Server (.NET 5), and I'd like to hide the side and top bars for a specific page. I tried searching but I couldn't find any solutions that worked. Below is a screenshot showing what I want to hide (in red rectangles).

[image: Image link]

Obviously, I want the content/body section itself to take up the whole page instead.

Comment: You can pass your layout page as a CascadingValue using "this" for the value, using a variable to show / hide it.  Then, in ANY page or control that wants to hide elements in the layout page, you can set the variable by picking up the layout as a CascadingParameter.  I'm off to work now, but I can show you the code later if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The top and side bar are defined in the `shared/MainLayout.razor` file. You can edit that file in order to edit the layout.

If you want to hide the top and side bars on only specific pages and not all the pages in your application, you can create a new layout component that does not have the top and side bar elements and then add the new layout to the selective pages using the `@layout` directive.

Create and apply new layout to component - [ASP.NET Core Blazor Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/layouts?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 13):

To future viewers of this question, here's what I did, I made a new file called 'NoMenuLayout.razor' in the 'Shared' folder, and put this code inside it:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page">
    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I went to the file in which I wanted to hide the top and side bar and simply put @layout NoMenuLayout right below the @page directive like this:

```
@page "/Landing"
@layout NoMenuLayout

<h3>Landing page test</h3>

@code {
    
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! In my case, I had to specify the full path for the file, like `@layout MyProject.Components.Layout.NoMenuLayout`