# Blazor components (Server-Side). Hide any shared component

Tags: .net, blazor

Is it possible to display only specific component in Blazor?
I dont want to display/show main menu or login button on the top. ONLY content of a particulate component. For example: show only 'Weather forecast' table when user navigates to a specific URL without showing any shared components like MainLayout or NavMenu.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blazor uses a default layout, it is `Shared\MainLayout.razor`
In there you can see how the menu and top row are setup.

First, define your own minimalist layout:

**Shared\ClearLayout.razor**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page">
    @Body
</div>
```

And then add 1 line to the top of `FetchData.razor`:

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@layout ClearLayout

<PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>

...
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is a duplicate question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69039751/blazor-hide-the-side-and-top-bar-on-a-specific-page-not-for-the-whole-site

Comment: Yes, that's right. StackOverflow doesn't make finding dupes very easy. I don't like the accepted answer there so I'll leave this one open.